# How to create separate DataBase with different tables for each client in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, devise

I want to create different database for each client when client signup using devise in rails application. But I don't know how to create and manage with parent database in my application. Please suggest me best solution.

Comment: why are you using different databases for each client? Else you can create a single table for client and use associations to map with other tables.

Comment: I want to create different database schema e.g. XyzClient12 for each client after signup and

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think You need to use `devise_group`

You need to create an extra `model User`

```
rails g devise User

rails g devise FirstUser
rails g devise SecondUser
rails g devise ThirdUser
```

and so on.......

Now you need to define it in your Application Controller

```
devise_group :everyone, contains: [:first_user, :second_user, :third_user]
```

but I prefer, what I have already said in my above comment.